# Trying to set a value in an array for invoice with the data that is going to filled in by the user in angular and c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, angular, typescript

I am trying to calculate the total amount in my invoiceLine, which is in an array.

[image: this is my html where i want the value to be]

This is my ts with the method im trying to show which is not working .When the user enters quantity and price it should auto calculate:

[image: this is my ts with the method im trying to show which is not working .When the user enters quantity and price it should auto calculate]

[image: also my ts]

Comment: Always add Code and Erormessages as **text** not image. Thank you. Edit this to avoid downvotes (which I won't but others will for sure.).

Comment: ^^ For more instructions on how to write a well-received question see [ask] and maybe also take the [tour]. Welcome to SO!

Comment: `totalAmount: y.quantity + y.unitprice` what do you expect here? You need to multiply!

Comment: its not even adding as well